# Search and Checkmarks in tableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a search bar in iOS and have made it to where it filters results and then when you click on it, it shows a checkmark. When I delete the search text, the check mark goes away and the full page of cells appears but the cell that I selected in the search is not selected with a check mark. Can someone please fix the code below to help me?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableSet *selectedUsers = [NSMutableSet set];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];


PFUser *user;
if (self.userResults != nil)
{
    user = [self.userResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.textLabel.text = user.username;


if ([selectedUsers containsObject:user])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
if ([selectedUsers containsObject:user])
{
    // user already selected

}
else
{
    // select user
    [selectedUsers addObject:user];
}


return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];
PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[friendsRelation addObject:user];
[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }    }];






}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableSet *selectedUsers = [NSMutableSet set];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier      forIndexPath:indexPath];  
PFUser *user;
if (self.userResults != nil)
{
     user = [self.userResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
     user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.textLabel.text = user.username; 
if ([selectedUsers containsObject:user])
{
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} 
     return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];
PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[friendsRelation addObject:user];
[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

}    }];

PFUser *user1;
if (self.userResults != nil)
{
     user1 = [self.userResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
     user1 = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selectedUsers removeObject:user1];
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selectedUsers addObject:user1];
}

}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: gIt still does't work. It does the exact same thing.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath ? can't you do it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: My guess ios that removing the user object in cellForRow is what's causing the trouble.

Comment: this one in cellForRow

Comment: I have put both methods above in my original post

Comment: That doesn't work. It says redefinition of user. When you delete the second definition of user (`PFUser *user;`), the text in the cells don't show up.

Comment: Edited. Check this one.

Comment: When I search down to the last result and click on it and then delete the search text, the checkmark is on the first cell in the tableview and not the cell that I picked

Comment: How do I make it so that the checkmark stays with user that is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that when you close the search bar the table view is reloaded.this time you have to record all the cells index path that user select.That is you do it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate Method,and save in an array value that user select.

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can check all the cell whose indexPath in in the array.

Hope you got it...

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { if
   ([selectedBillsArray containsObject:indexPath])    {
                  cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;    }        

   }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
       {
           [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

           [selectedBillsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath];
       }
       else
       {
           [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
          [selectedBillsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath];
       }
       }
```

Do something like this...